# Oozie shell action memory limit

Tags: oozie, hadoop-yarn

We have an oozie workflow with a shell action that needs more memory than what a map task is given by Yarn by default.

How can we give it more memory?

We have tried adding the following configuration to the action:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>6144</value> <!-- for example -->
  </property>
</configuration>
```

We have both set this as an inline (in the workflow.xml) configuration and as a jobXml.
Neither has had any effect.

Answer (score 19):

We found the answer:

A shell action is executed as an oozie "launcher" map task, and this task does not use the normal configuration properties.

Instead you have to prefix the properties with "oozie.launcher" to make them apply to the launcher task.

So in our case, if we use the following configuration for our shell action, it works.

```xml
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
        <value>6144</value> <!-- for example -->
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

This is not obvious from the oozie documentation.
We found this here:
http://downright-amazed.blogspot.com/2012/02/configure-oozies-launcher-job.html

Answer (score 0):

thank your point,
just edit workflow.xml file, add :

```xml
<workflow-app name="simple-ONE-wf" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    <start to='ONE'/>`enter code here
    <action name="ONE">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
                    <value>4096</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
                    <value>-Xmx3200m</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
                    <value>-XX:MaxPermSize=1g</value>
                </property>
                ...
            </configuration>
           ...
    </action>

    <kill name='kill'>
        <message>Something went wrong: ${wf:errorCode('firstdemo')}</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end'/>
</workflow-app>
```

Comment: What's the value added by this answer compared to the (clearer, IMO) existing one posted 3 years ago?

Comment: more details, it is very clearer, can just used, i meet perm OOM, only to add memory is no use, must to add opts and to set -XX:MaxPermSize=1g

Comment: Wow, if you're targeting Java 7 or earlier. Java 8 has been released even before this question has been asked. Please make it clear in your answer, explain how it's different and where/when it can be used.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: the configuration needs to be at the action section. not at the workflow section. correct?