# Pig : Container is running beyond physical memory limits in cdh 5 using oozie

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie

I'm trying to run a simple pig script which running f9 in grunt shell but not working with oozie ,getting error like this:

Container [pid=2617,containerID=container_1438923434512_12103_01_000002] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 1.0 GB of 1 GB physical memory used; 2.9 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used. Killing container. Dump of the process-tree for container_1438923434512_12103_01_000002..

actually i'm calling a shell script through oozie which intern calls pig script and getting error like that.

How could i make it workable in oozie

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the default for YARN container size on that cluster (1 GB of RAM) is way too low for your job.

But it's not clear whether the YARN error shown relates to the Shell action (running `grunt`) or to a child MapReduce execution.

**Plan A -** Assuming that it's the child MapReduce execution that requires more RAM, on top of the `grunt` script just add

```
set mapreduce.map.memory.mb    5120
set mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb 5120
```

Reference: [Pig documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/cmds.html#run), [YARN documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html#Configuring_Hadoop_in_Non-Secure_Mode)

**Plan B -** If it is actually the Shell action that requires more RAM, add some configuration in `workflow.xml`

```
<action name="PiggyBack">
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.2">
      <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
      <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>

      <configuration>
         <property>
            <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>5120</value>
         </property>
      </configuration>
```

*etc.*

Reference: I found the hint myself a few months back from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262896/oozie-shell-action-memory-limit) so I suggest you give it a +1 if it was helpful...