# How to handle varying input batch size in mapreduce jobs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Issue -

I am running a series of mapreduce jobs wrapped in an oozie workflow. Input data consists of a bunch text files most of which are fairly small (KBs) but every now and then I get files over 1-2 MB which cause my jobs to fail. I am seeing two reasons why jobs are failing - one, inside one or two mr jobs the file is parsed into a graph in memory and for a bigger file its mr is running out of memory and two, the jobs are timing out.

Questions -

1) I believe I can just disable the timeout by setting mapreduce.task.timeout to 0. But I am not able to find any documentation that mention any risk in doing this.

2) For the OOM error, what are the various configs I can mess around with ? Any links here on potential solutions and risks would be very helpful.

3)I see a lot of "container preempted by scheduler" messages before I finally get OOM.. is this a seperate issue or related? How do I get around this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the timeout: no need to set it to "unlimited", a reasonably large value can do *(e.g. in our Prod cluster it is set to 300000)*.

About requiring a non-standard RAM quota in Oozie: the properties you are looking for are probably `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` for global YARN container quota, `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.java.opts` to instruct the JVM about that quota (i.e. fail gracefully with OOM exception instead of crashing the container with no useful error message), and the `.reduce.` counterparts.

See also [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262896/oozie-shell-action-memory-limit/) for the (very poorly documented) `oozie.launcher.` prefix in case you want to set properties for a non-MR Action -- e.g. a Shell, or a Java program that spawns indirectly a series of Map and Reduce steps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot to mention that when I get OOO errors theres also usually "container preempted by scheduler" with it (updating my original post to include this)... any ideas if that means I should be changing some other values as well or how to get around this?

Comment: Gaaah! Your SysAdmin has activated either **Fair Scheduler** or **Capacity Scheduler**, with **preemption** -- e.g. a "license to kill" any container that is running peacefully in a low-priority queue as soon as a high-priority queue starts howling for blood - er, for capacity. Your best hope is to bribe that SysAdmin so as to get access to a higher-priority queue (cf. property `mapred.job.queue.name`) or change the default settings for your user and/or your default queue.

Comment: For an intro about preemption you may look at this post http://jason4zhu.blogspot.fr/2014/11/fair-scheduler-in-yarn-hadoop-2.2.0-experiment-on-preemption.html or that post http://www.4-traders.com/HORTONWORKS-INC-19157091/news/Hortonworks--Better-SLAs-via-Resource-preemption-in-YARNrsquos-CapacityScheduler-20570275/ (courtesy of Google)

Comment: I will check it out. Thank you!