# Oozie workflow is not considering username specified in the parameter "mapreduce.job.user.name"

Tags: oozie, hiveql

I am running a Oozie workflow (for hive sql) and in that I have specified a parameter "`mapreduce.job.user.name`" where I have given an user name which is having access to execute the job. I have also declared another parameter "`password`" there I have defined the password of this user. Unfortunately during running the job Oozie is not considering the user which I have given in the parameter "`mapreduce.job.user.name`" and considering the login user name. Now the login user doesn't have access to execute the job, so it is failing with error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
```

Question is why Oozie is not considering the user which is specified in the parameter "`mapreduce.job.user.name`". Do I have to define any other parameter?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438052/job-queue-for-hive-action-in-oozie/32438566#32438566

Comment: not getting much help from the given URL

Comment: Long story short: when you run a MR Action then you can use the usual Hadoop properties; but when you run a Shell / Java / Hive / Pig Action, then Oozie first starts a **launcher** job -- and properties applicable for that launcher job must be prefixed by `oozie.launcher.`

Comment: Another take: `oozie.launcher.mapreduce.job.user.name` will set the user name for the Hive Action itself; but `mapreduce.job.user.name` will apply to the child YARN jobs used for running queries.