# Using ENV vars in distributed Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, oozie, ambari, bigdata

My goal is to run applications on our Hadoop cluster without putting the explicit configuration into each app. Therefore, I am trying to put the configurations of the cluster into ENV variables and propagate them to each node in the cluster.

For example I define:

```
export HIVE2_JDBC_URL=jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

to use it like this later on:

```
beeline -u $HIVE2_JDBC_URL/<db_name> -e "SELECT * FROM <table_name>;"
```

While this works for this specific use case (in the cli) it has two big drawbacks:

- I have to manually update the ENV variables on each node on changes
- Oozie workflows can not read from ENV variables

Is there a way to use Ambari to retrieve this settings and can I define my own custom settings that are then available on each node? Is there an approach that works also in Oozie workflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force **"cluster-wide" environment variables** via `mapred-site.xml` and `yarn-site.xml` -- but I'm not 100% sure which properties must be set in the configuration of the **ResourceManager** service, and/or every **NodeManager** service, and/or **client nodes**. And which level overrides (or adds to) which level. You will have to do some research & experimentation.

Look into the documentation for `mapred-default.xml` and `yarn-default.xml` (e.g. [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) and [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) for Hadoop 2.7.0) for properties such as...

```
mapred.child.env
mapreduce.admin.user.env
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.admin.user.env
yarn.nodemanager.admin-env
yarn.nodemanager.env-whitelist
```

*[Edit]* look also into these properties that have no proper entry in the "default" listings (yet another documentation bug...) and forget about the "mapred.child" stuff

```
mapreduce.map.env 
mapreduce.reduce.env
```

---

For **Oozie jobs**, there are two ways to set env. variables:

- Shell actions have an explicit `<env-var>VAR=VALUE</env-var>` syntax, because shell scripts rely *a lot* on env. variables
- all actions that use a "launcher" YARN job *(i.e. Java, Pig, Sqoop, Spark, Hive, Hive2, Shell...)* can benefit from a
     `<property>`
      `<name>oozie.launcher.xxx.xxx.xxx.env</name><value>****</value>`
    `</property>`
  to override the values in client config files that are mentioned above
- MapReduce actions are launched directly, there is no "launcher" job, so the property would be set directly as
     `<property>`
      `<name>xxx.xxx.xxx.env</name><value>****</value>`
    `</property>`
- in addition, the actions defined in the core Workflow schema *(i.e. Java, Pig, MapReduce)* can use the `<global>` section to define the property just once
   => alas, the other actions are defined as plug-ins with a distinct XML schema, and do not inherit the Global properties...

Unfortunately the documentation for Oozie (e.g. [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/index.html) for Oozie 4.1) is completely silent about the `oozie.launcher.*` properties, you will have to make some research in Stack Overflow -- in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438052/job-queue-for-hive-action-in-oozie) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a very nice overview. I ended up auto-generating property files in my case.