# Oozie setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am running a java program (not MR) via oozie. This is referring to some native libraries and I tried setting the following

```
    <configuration>
                    <property>
                        <name>mapreduce.map.env</name>
                        <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/tableau/</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>mapreduce.child.env</name>
                        <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/tableau/</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
                        <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/tableau/</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>mapreduce.reduce.env</name>
                        <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/tableau/</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
                        <value>-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/tableau/</value>
                    </property>
</configuration>
```

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/tableau/

Anyhow my program does not seem to read these path and I am getting the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'TableauHyperExtract': libTableauHyperExtract.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:194)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:283)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:244)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.register(Native.java:1065)
    at com.tableausoftware.hyperextract.ExtractAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: **1.** Are you sure that Tableau is installed on all cluster nodes? **2.** Are you aware that the Oozie launcher ignores standard Hadoop properties and enforces only props prefixed by `oozie.launcher.` ?  _(not documented, alas... but there are multiple posts about that on StackOverflow)_ ?

Comment: Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438052/job-queue-for-hive-action-in-oozie for instance

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter - Adding oozie.launcher works. It was difficult as I could not find a documentation for this. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefixed the properties with oozie.launcher as suggested by @SamsonScharfrichter and it works perfect.

```
 <property>
   <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.env</name>
   <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/tableau/</value>
</property>
```