# Correct way to specify job queue name in oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I want my oozie workflow actions to launch job in a different queue than default one . I tried setting mapred.job.queue.name and oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name in configuration properties of each action and both seems to work fine and  do the same thing i.e. launch the action/job in specified queue name. I wanted to understand what is the difference between these two properties. And is there any way i can set queue name globally for complete workflow like in job.properties so that i dont have to mention it in each action.

Comment: The answer is: "it depends on the Action type". Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337362/oozie-properties-defined-in-file-referenced-in-global-job-xml-not-visible-in-wo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438052/job-queue-for-hive-action-in-oozie/32438566

Comment: While you are at it, have a look at the "gotcha" mentioned here https://blog.cloudera.com/untangling-apache-hadoop-yarn-part-5-using-fairscheduler-queue-properties/ >> note that in Ooize V5 the _launcher_ stub runs inside the AM container, whereas in V4 it would run in a separate container (which means 2 containers, one for the AM and one for the launcher)

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter this was very helpful . Got few new things to learn by this.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter In workflow.xml I am setting oozie.launcher.mapred.job.queue.name to a user specific queue as configuration property for hive2 action and launching oozie workflow. Launcher job (driver) for hive2 actions is getting submitted in user specific queue but the actual mapreduce job which is executed by hive2 action launcher is getting submitted to default queue . How can i get user specific queue propagated to action mapreduce job which hive executes

Comment: Oozie "hive2" action works exactly like a `beeline` thin client - it connects to HiveServer2 and submits commands. HS2 uses its default configuration unless you change them dynamically **with HQL command `set <hive session property> = <value>`**

Comment: Works also with some `<Hadoop properties>` that HS2 lets you change; you have to experiment. Same with `<TEZ-specific properties>` when using TEZ as the execution engine instead of MapReduce _(note that when HS2 uses a "warmed up" TEZ session it's too late to change some properties because the YARN job is already running, that's the point of "warming up")_