# Set ipc.client.connect.timeout for oozie workflow

Tags: hadoop, configuration, oozie

I'm new to oozie and have a problem: we need to configure ipc.client.connect.timeout for one wokflow only (all of it's actions, including shell-action), not changing settings for entire cluster (we're using CDH). I tried to change it in *global*  block of workflow.xml, but it didn't work.

Where should i change this parameter?

Comment: Basically, in **each** action, using property `oozie.launcher.ipc.client.connect.timeout` (at least with Oozie 4.x - there was some massive refactoring in V5.0 and I haven't used the newer versions yet)

Comment: For more context on the non-documented and badly-documented parts of Oozie, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337362/oozie-properties-defined-in-file-referenced-in-global-job-xml-not-visible-in-wo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32438052/job-queue-for-hive-action-in-oozie